# Pades Signature with multiple DSS Dictionaries

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, pades

I'm working on a PDF Signer/Validator and don't know how I should handle pdf files with multiple signatures and dss dictionaries.

Here is the scenario: A pdf file is signed  twice, and after the second signature, a DSS dictionary is added with the CRLs, CERTs and OCSPs of both signatures:

```
[ Signature 1 ]
[ Signature 2 ]
DSS << 
    VRI << 
        /HashSignature1 10 0 R
        /HashSignature2 11 0 R
    >>
    ...
>>
```

So far, so good. Both signatures are covered in the only DSS dictionary on the document. But someone else decided to sign this same document, and also add his CRLs and everything else. Then, I must create a new DSS dictionary, and my question is: Must the old signatures, already covered in another DSS dictionary, be in this one? I think so, since the DSS is inside an updated document catalog (and you removed the reference to the last dictionary), but there is little agreement in the company.

```
[ Signature 1 ]
[ Signature 2 ]
DSS << 
    VRI <<
        /HashSignature1 10 0 R
        /HashSignature2 11 0 R
    >>
    ...
>>
[ Signature 3 ]
DSS << 
    VRI <<
        /HashSignature1 10 0 R
        /HashSignature2 11 0 R
        /HashSignature3 16 0 R
    >>
    ...
>>
```

OR

```
[ Signature 1 ]
[ Signature 2 ]
DSS << 
    VRI <<
        /HashSignature1 10 0 R
        /HashSignature2 11 0 R
    >>
    ...
>>
[ Signature 3 ]
DSS << 
    VRI <<
        /HashSignature3 16 0 R
    >>
    ...
>>
```

Are both of them correct? Only one of them? With one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrea Valle, from Adobe, clarified this for me by e-mail:

> This has been discussed within ESI for some time, and finally the team decided to clarify this in EN 319 142-1.
>
> See section 5.4.1 on page 11 of version 1.1.0:
>
> The life-time of the protection can be further extended beyond the life-time of the last document time-stamp applied by adding further DSS information to validate the previous last document time-stamp along with a new document time-stamp. Every time a DSS Dictionary is updated during incremental update, it **should** contain the values from the previous DSS Dictionary.
>
> > NOTE: In general the DSS Dictionary will contain validation data from previous revisions plus validation data added for the current revision. If entries are removed from a DSS Dictionary during an incremental update the set of validation data might not be complete for validation of the signatures, but replacement of validation data - like e.g. more up-to-date certificate status information - might be performed for optimization reasons.

So it's actually **recommended** to add all entries from the older DSS dictionary, but not **mandatory**. You can update these entries if they don't break the signature, but that's optional.

Reading a little bit further on the same document:

> The Document Security Store (DSS) shall be a dictionary that shall have the value DSS as key in the document catalog dictionary. This dictionary is used to provide a single place where all of the validation-related information for some or all signatures in the document should be placed.

The DSS is intended to provide a **single** place where **all** information **should** be placed.

So, if you don't place all information there, you're not breaking anything, but you're not using the DSS as intended.

Then, the answer is: a pdf signer should use the first approach, but a pdf validator should be prepared for the second.

---

EDIT:

Actually, any PAdES validator should check either the DSS entries existed earlier anyway. If you check only the lastest one, it's possible to re-validate an invalid signature, if the CA certificate used to sign the CRLs or OCSPs was compromissed latter, and this fake information was added in the latest DSS.

Example:

1. Sig 1 was made with an revoked certificate
2. All DSS entries are added, and the signature is sure to be invalid
3. A DocumentTimeStamp is added, protecting this DSS.
4. **Sig 1 CA certificate is compromissed**
5. Sig 2 is made, with a valid certificate
6. Sig 2 DSS entries are added, LTV-enabling the signature
7. Sig 1 CRL/OCSP is replaced with a fake one made with the compromissed CA certificate

In this situation, a validator that relies on the lattest DSS will validate Sig 1, when it shouldn't. That's why you add a DocumentTimeStamp to protect the information about that signature.

---

TL;DR:

Both options are right. The DSS should have information about all signatures, but it's not mandatory. And a validator should check the DSS that was made right after the signature, not only the latest one.

Comment: *So it's indeed mandatory...* - no, not **mandatory**, merely **recommended** ('should', not 'shall').

Comment: @mkl You're right. It's actually recommended, I'll update the answer with a few more points.

Comment: Please be aware that how exactly you should and should not handle PAdES LTV information, depends on your very use case. You might even explicitly throw away some information not needed in the context at hand. Whether or not time stamps are used, depends on the use case and PAdES profile, too.

Answer (score 0):

As there's only a single DSS entry in the Catalog dictionary you need to update the existing DSS dicionary (resp. the VRI dictionary and the other values).

Comment: I understand and agree with you that this is the best approach. But is it mandatory? the older DSS is still embed, and the older catalog still references it.

If it's not mandatory, the validation part of the software will have to deal with multiple DSS entries.

Comment: But the DSS entry can only point to a single object. And you're required to update at least this entry or its content. It is not possible to access an object of a previous revision (by default). Just because you have several Catalog dictionaries in your PDF source only one of it is the correct/latest one.

Comment: I totally agree with you it should be, but it's actually not mandatory =(. 

See my answer for more.